# Calling of c# function using Ajax Javascript on asp:Button click , is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using below code to check that if the value I am entering in Tetxbox already exist in Database, then show an alert "value already exist". For this I am using Ajax Javascript on asp:Button ("Save") click:

**Ajax Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("[id*=btnBar]").bind("click", function () {

                alert("helloooo");

                var chk = {};
                chk.requestID = $("[id*=lblGuidId]").text();
                alert(chk.requestID);
                chk.barCode = $("[id*=txtBar]").val();
                alert(chk.barCode);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "Demo.aspx/SaveUser",
                    data: '{chk: ' + JSON.stringify(chk) + '}',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                    var val = data.isUserInserted;
                    alert(val);

                    if (val == true) {
                        alert("Barcode No. alredy exist");
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Barcode No. does not exist");
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("error" + data);
                },
                });
                return false;

                alert("End click");
            });
        });       
    </script>
```

**HTML code:**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblGuidId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RequestID") %>'></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBarcodeNumber" runat="server" MaxLength="11" Width="230px" Text='<%# Bind("BarcodeNo") %>' Display="None" OnTextChanged="TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnBar" runat="server" Text="Save"/>
```

**c# Code:**

```
public class Check
{
    public Guid? requestID { get; set; }
    public string barCode { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static bool SaveUser(Check chk)
{
    bool isUserInserted = false;

    string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MasterDB"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Invoice.usp_tbl_Request_Select_CheckDuplicateBarcode_Test", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestID", chk.requestID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BarcodeNo", chk.barCode);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        isUserInserted = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();
    }
    return isUserInserted;
}
```

but everytime it goes into **else** , if data exist in database then also it goes into **else** part. Here, I want to check that If c# WebMethod `bool isuserInserted` is returning true then it should prompt alert "already exist" else if c# WebMethod `bool isuserInserted` is returning false then it should prompt alert "does not exist".

Please reply what is missing in my code.

Please note that I am first time using this Ajax Javascript.

Comment: Where is the javascript you are using?  Likely the reason it is not working on the OnClick event is that the javascript is failing.  When a client click fails the server click is never called.

Comment: Two observations: 1) Save user parameter in webmethod is 'chk', but in your javascript code, you have mentioned the parameter as 'user'. 2) Try adding an error callback and find out that the actual exception. Example code ->  error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { }

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh: Thank you so much for the reply. I changed 'user' to 'chk' in JQuery code (updated in posted question), now `$.ajax` is executing but everytime it goes in `else` statement. If the Textbox value already exist in Database then also it goes in `else`. Please let me know what shall I change in my code so that it should work as expected. Also, in this JQuery line `var val=data.isUserInserted;` `alert(val);` I get undefined. Please let me know what is missing in my code. I am first time using this JQuery Ajax call

Comment: Your method simply returns a boolean; what if you do `var val=data;` instead of the .isUserInserted appended

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: I tried `var val=data;` and checked the result into alert , I get `[object Object]`. Please let me know how to call the boolean return value in Ajax JQuery, so that based on its value I can check the condition ? Please reply

Comment: If you run the debugger up to the line where it returns a value in the c# code, does it return what you expect in all cases?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: Yes it(`return isuserInserted`) returns true if value exist. But how to call this inside JQuery ?

Comment: I added code in my answer which SHOULD work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
**var val = data.d** instead of var **val =  data.isUserInserted**.

it will be work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Your solution worked. Please let me know what is this `.d` in the code ?

Comment: Sure. Just let me know what is `.d` stands for in the code that you suggested. and thank you for the help

Comment: For know about .d use this code inside success function : alert(JSON.stringfy(data)); you will get your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help. 1 last thing I want to ask that how to check the error in Ajax JQuery. Suppose if at any point error occurs, then how to trace that what could be the possible reason of error ? Please reply

Comment: You can use this line of code inside of error function of ajax jquery : alert(data.responseText). This will be work great for trace error in ajax jquery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84979/discussion-between-user3196511-and-mukesh-dutt).

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of the .net need you to add a datafilter to ensure it gets the right thing:

Note use data.d is ok but this (dataFilter) makes it version proof so that it works either way and you don't have to change code when you update/upgrade your version on the server side.

This will do that:

```
dataFilter: function(data)
        {
            var msg;
            if (typeof (JSON) !== 'undefined' &&
            typeof (JSON.parse) === 'function')
                msg = JSON.parse(data);
            else
                msg = eval('(' + data + ')');
            if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
                return msg.d;
            else
                return msg;
        },
```

SO your code for the ajax call would look like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "Demo.aspx/SaveUser",
    data: '{chk: ' + JSON.stringify(chk) + '}',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataFilter: function (data) {
        var msg;
        if (typeof (JSON) !== 'undefined' && typeof (JSON.parse) === 'function') msg = JSON.parse(data);
        else msg = eval('(' + data + ')');
        if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d')) return msg.d;
        else return msg;
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

        var val = data.isUserInserted;
        alert(val);

        if (val == true) {
            alert("Barcode No. alredy exist");
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            alert("Barcode No. does not exist");
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("error" + data);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the value of **alert(val)** if that is returning true.
Then you use **===** for equality which is check value and data type as well or you parse the value **val to Boolean**.

Comment: alert (val) is giving Undefined. Please let me know how to call the boolean return value in Ajax JQuery, so that based on its value I can check the condition ? Please reply

Comment: Use  var val = data.d instead of var val =  data.isUserInserted.  it will be work.